# Neo4j Cypher - Collect two array values return one object

Tags: arrays, neo4j, cypher

I have multiple nodes with same label. The node properties have two arrays. I want join both array values to an object or a map.

Example:

- Array one: `[1,2,3,4,5]`
- Array two: `[5,4,3,2,1]`

I want to return result as `{output:[{1,5},{2,4},{3,3},{4,2},{5,1}]}` so a total of 5 objects in that output result.

Is this possible in Cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5] AS array_one, [5,4,3,2,1] AS array_two
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(array_one) - 1) AS i
WITH [array_one[i], array_two[i]] AS output
WITH COLLECT(output) AS output_list
RETURN {outputs: output_list}
```

That will give you a map, whose sole value is a list of lists. If you want to dynamically build a list of maps instead (your question's syntax is ambiguous), you will have to look into `apoc`, Cypher doesn't natively support dynamic key assignment.

Answer (score 3):

APOC procedures may be the way to go on this one. In the [Collection Functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) section, the procedure you want is `apoc.coll.zip([list1],[list2])`. It is similar to what you want, but not exact. Rather than returning a list of objects, it will return a list of list pairs:

```
with [1,2,3,4,5] as list1, [5,4,3,2,1] as list2
call apoc.coll.zip(list1,list2) yield value
return {outputs:value}
// returns {outputs:[[1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1]]}
```

Regarding your desired output, objects in Cypher are like JSON objects and consist of key/value pairs, so it is impossible to return it in the format you're describing. You can test this for yourself.

```
// this works just fine
return {output: [[1,2]]}

// this causes a syntax error
return {output: [{1,2}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Array of maps

You can generate a map containing an array of *maps* without using APOC:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5] AS a1, [5,4,3,2,1] AS a2
RETURN {output: REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(a1)-1) | s + {one: a1[i], two: a2[i]})} AS res;
```

The output is:

```
{output:[{"one":1,"two":5},{"one":2,"two":4},{"one":3,"two":3},{"one":4,"two":2},{"one":5,"two":1}]}
```

#### Array of arrays

To generate a map containing an array of *arrays*:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5] AS a1, [5,4,3,2,1] AS a2
RETURN {output: REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(a1)-1) | s + [[a1[i], a2[i]]])} AS res;
```

The output is:

```
{output:[[1,5],[2,4],[3,3],[4,2],[5,1]]}
```